# Server rejects all ipv4 traffic, but allows ipv6 (Bash/Ubuntu on Windows)

Tags: windows-10, bash, ssh, ipv6, ipv4

I've been trying to set up a home server, with admittedly a home ISP (Comcast). I have been able to connect to my HomePC using the ipv6 address. However, this doesn't work well, since the address seems to change a lot. So I am using `inadyn` to monitor and update my ipv4 address. The only problem is that my computer seems to reject all ipv4 traffic.

See below I've pinged myself using first the ipv4 (100% packet loss) and the ipv6 (0% packet loss).

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHR0n.png]

I am at a loss of how to allow the ipv4 traffic onto my machine.

Comment: Your home router responds to IPv4 pings, because of NAT. These never reach your computers behind the router. Check the router's configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for the suggestions. I have been trying to change the settings you're talking about all day long. There is nothing really there. I even went so far as to install Ubuntu on my computer and I am dual-booting. I tried pinging myself, with the same problem. I tethered the computer to my phone (in Ubuntu and Windows), same problem.

Comment: You haven't even told us what router you have!

Comment: Sorry about that: http://arris.force.com/consumers/ConsumerProductDetail?p=a0ha000000TnNmSAAV&c=Touchstone%20Modems%20and%20Gateways